# Segmentation Fault randomly at pclose while retrieving the PID

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, arm, gdb

I am running a simple C Application which will get PID Of an process continuously.
This is running on an custom ARM Board.

```
pid_t GetStreamerPID()
{
    pid_t pid = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    char line[100];
    char command[50] = "pidof -s gst-launch-0.10"; 
    memset(line, '\0', 100);
    FILE *cmd = popen(command, "r");

    if ( cmd == NULL )
    {
    perror("Popen\n");
    exit(0);
    }    
    ret = fread(line, sizeof(char), 20, cmd);
    pclose(cmd);    
    pid = atoi(line);
    return pid;
}
```

Randomly, the code is throwing segmentation Fault at pclose.. I am debugging this from past week and I am unable to find out the cause of the issue.

Attaching gdb backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76e3a588 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x76e3a588 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x76e25c20 in fclose@@GLIBC_2.4 () from /lib/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000109b4 in GetStreamerPID () at getPid.c:111
        pid = 0
        ret = 0
        line = '\000' <repeats 99 times>
        command = "pidof -s gst-launch-0.10", '\000' <repeats 25 times>
        cmd = 0x136c008
#3  0x00010a50 in startStreamer () at getPid.c:147
        command = '\000' <repeats 255 times>
        pid = 0
#4  0x0001087c in CheckVideoState () at getPid.c:81
        iVideoOn = 1
#5  0x00010a20 in MainLoop () at getPid.c:137
No locals.
#6  0x00010b74 in main () at getPid.c:183
No locals.
```

Also, one more wierd observation is , after I close gdb and run "reboot" command it throws segmentation fault. Again this is random, it can be any command..

I can provide you as much as information you want. Please help me in debugging this wierd issue...

Comment: Please don't paste all your code into Stack Overflow. Take the time to write a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve) and people will be more inclined/able to help you.

Comment: Hi, This is just a component of my main application, which is causing the issue.. I have been trying to find out the fault from the past two week and still no success.. So, had to come to Stack Overflow for your help

Comment: Regardless. Way too much code. Nobody has time to understand what your program is doing. Hire a freelancer if you want *that* much code fixed for you.

Comment: I thought the whole code will be helpful.. Anyhow, it is only in the GetStreamerPID() pclose() function the program crashes with Segmentation Fault..

Comment: Then please edit the rest out of the post.

Comment: Ok.. I have removed the whole code, and just kept the function that is crashing...

Comment: Question: Why `char command[50] = "pidof -s gst-launch-0.10"; popen(command,"r");` instead of `popen("pidof -s gst-launch-0.10","r");`?

Comment: Yes, previously it was the same statement. In that case, the segfault was occurring at popen, when I made changes by having a variables, segfault switched to pclose..

Comment: Does all of the code compile without warnings?

Comment: This `... read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); if (strlen(buffer) > 0)  { ...`looks critical. At least if the data returned does not contain any `'\0', on which `strlen()` relies. If the `'\0'` is missing `strlen()` reads beyond `buffer`'s boundary, proking the infamous Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen form then on. Why not change this to use what `read()` returns instead of `strlen()`. You should take into account `read()`'s result anyways to perform proper error checking.

Comment: Also I see the PThread header included. Should it be you did not show to "real" code? ;-)

Comment: Anything in the system logs? If the `reboot` command is segfaulting, I'd check if you're out of virtual memory or there's some corruption due to disk or memory errors..

Comment: Yes, the code compiles without warning, I added -Wall option for compilation..Pthreads are not used..Initial code was using pthreads but not now. Note: This happens randomly after some calls. Only it is the next few calls that randomly fails with seg fault.. How we can check for memory errors..

Answer (score 0):

Your crash is happening inside `free`.

Any such crash is a 99.99% sign that you have heap corruption *elsewhere*, and very likely has absolutely nothing to do with the code you've shown, or with `pclose`.

Tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org), [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), or GLIBC [mcheck](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) are your best bet.

Comment: You can see, my code is nowhere performing any memory allocation/deallocations. It's all local variables. How can it corrupt the heap? I cannot use Address Sanitizer as it only supports Android on ARM not the Linux image generated by buildroot.

Comment: @md.jamal The code you show is not the problem. The problem is *elsewhere*.

Comment: What is the best way to debug this. When I run under valgrind, it says "The impossible Happened" and under gdb it shows "??" , corrupted stack frame..

Comment: @md.jamal Do you read answers at all? I feel like I have to repeat everything twice. "What's the best way to debug this?" -- I've shown you *three* best ways (you appear to have tried only one of them).

Comment: Address sanitizer doesn't work on ARM based board running Linux. will try mcheck...